# Absolute positioned div won't stay in place

Tags: absolute

Okay so I have these divs called "latestWorkTitle" which are positioned absolute and are placed on top of the corresponding image to show its title.

However, I can't get this properly to work. The titles don't show at the corresponding image and when I resize my browser window everything shifts and so on.

I tried creating this jsbin http://jsbin.com/uhoxef/1 with a part of my code to illustrate how it should look like and what is going wrong. Even all the titles go on top of each other in the code while they should be on top of the corresponding images... I'm just basically totally lost at this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the HTML was confusing itself. I also made the thumbnail class the relative layer. HTML renders as we read, from left to right. So putting the title before the image causes the image to show on top and cover the text.

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <a href="portfoliodetail.php?id=10">
    <img src="http://www.hlnarchitects.com/img/plain_red.png" />
    <div class="latestWorkTitle">title1</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;}

.portfolioOverview img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;}

.latestWorkTitle {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 6px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;}
```

For this to work, each `thumbnail` class needs to be the `relative` start for each individual layer. So the `thumbnail` class is set to relative. 
Any object set to `absolute` (`.latestWorkTitle`) within this layer will start from the `top` and `left` position of the relative object.

You'll need to adjust some details to taste but I hope this helps.